# Entity Framework T4 templates build issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, t4

I am wondering if anyone has experienced this...I have a bunch of projects in my solution but there are two that randomly fails when I change the code in them...

Model and Data.

I am using the EF T4 temmplates to generate my models and dbcontext from an edmx file.

In my Model project which builds first, I have the T4 template pointing to my EDMX file in my data project:

```
const string inputFile = @"../Alpha.Data/Alpha.edmx";
```

Then my Data project builds after (it depends on Model completing first).

But a lot of times the Data project fails because it can't find the POCO objects in the models it seems:

```
C:\Dropbox\Dev\Alpha\src\Alpha.Data\Alpha.Context.cs(104,26,104,45): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BlockedEmailAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This will eventually work after building/cleaning a couple times. But it's really annoying. It almost seems the Data project builds before the Model T4 finishes.

I've checked to make sure all my projects are set to build under Configuration Manager

Comment: Maybe code generation is not triggered with each re-build. Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx